# Making a tkinter function not show in next window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, sqlite, dropbox

I have a tkinter window with login function that allows one of three people login for an airport login system, "HQ", "Pilot/Crew" or "customer".

So far I can make the user and I can login with the sql being used.

The problem is I am not sure how to turn the Dropbox into the widget and because of this it doesn't disappear in the next window.

```
    # imports
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
import sqlite3

# make database and users (if not exists already) table at programme start up
with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
    c = db.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (var TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL ,password TEXT NOT NULL);')
db.commit()
db.close()

# main Class


class main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #  Window
        self.master = master
        # Some Usefull variables
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        self.n_username = StringVar()
        self.n_password = StringVar()
        # Create Widgets
        self.widgets()

    # def pack():
    #     if self.var.get() = "HQ"

    # Login Function
    def login(self):
        # Establish Connection
        with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        # Find user If there is any take proper action
        find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE var = ? and username = ? and password = ?')
        c.execute(find_user, [(self.var.get()), (self.username.get()), (self.password.get())])
        result = c.fetchall()
        if result:
            self.logf.pack_forget()

            self.head['text'] = self.username.get() + '\n Loged In'
            self.head['pady'] = 150

        else:
            ms.showerror('Oops!', 'something is not right.')


    def new_user(self):
        # Establish Connection
        with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()

        # Find Existing username if any take proper action
        find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?')
        c.execute(find_user, [(self.username.get())])
        if c.fetchall():
            ms.showerror('Error!', 'Username Taken Try a Diffrent One.')
        else:
            ms.showinfo('Success!', 'Account Created!')
            self.log()
        # Create New Account
        insert = 'INSERT INTO user(var,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?)'
        c.execute(insert, [(self.var.get()), (self.n_username.get()), (self.n_password.get())])
        db.commit()

    def dropbox(self):
        OPTIONS = [
            "Please Select",
            "HQ",
            "Pilot/Crew",
            "Customer"
        ]
        self.var.set(OPTIONS[0])
        dropdownmenu = OptionMenu(root, self.var, OPTIONS[0], OPTIONS[1], OPTIONS[2], OPTIONS[3])
        dropdownmenu.pack()


        # Frame Packing Methords
    def log(self):

        self.username.set('')
        self.password.set('')
        self.crf.pack_forget()
        self.head['text'] = 'LOGIN'
        self.logf.pack()

    def cr(self):
        self.n_username.set('')
        self.n_password.set('')
        self.logf.pack_forget()
        self.head['text'] = 'Create Account'
        self.crf.pack()

    # Draw Widgets
    def widgets(self):
        self.head = Label(self.master, text='LOGIN', font=('', 35), pady=10)
        self.head.pack()
        self.logf = Frame(self.master, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.dropbox()
        Label(self.logf, text='Username: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(row=2, column=0)
        Entry(self.logf, textvariable=self.username, bd=5, font=('', 15)).grid(row=2, column=1)
        Label(self.logf, text='Password: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
        Entry(self.logf, textvariable=self.password, bd=5, font=('', 15), show='*').grid(row=3, column=1)
        Button(self.logf, text='Login', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.login).grid()
        Button(self.logf, text='Create Account', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.cr).grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.logf.pack()

        self.crf = Frame(self.master, padx=10, pady=10)
        Label(self.crf, text='Select:', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(self.crf, text='Username: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
        Entry(self.crf, textvariable=self.n_username, bd=5, font=('', 15)).grid(row=2, column=1)
        Label(self.crf, text='Password: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
        Entry(self.crf, textvariable=self.n_password, bd=5, font=('', 15), show='*').grid(row=3, column=1)
        Button(self.crf, text='Create Account', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.new_user).grid()
        Button(self.crf, text='Go to Login', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.log).grid(row=4, column=1)


# create window and application object
root = tk.Tk()
# root.title("Login Form")
main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

That is my code at the moment, it works.

Also anyone know how to change the dropbox from .pack() to .grid() as I would like to locate it i gave up on that but it still bugs me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify `dropbox()` to have one more argument: the parent, and return the created `OptionMenu` (use the `parent` argument as its parent instead of `root`) like below:

```
def dropbox(self, parent):
    OPTIONS = [
        "Please Select",
        "HQ",
        "Pilot/Crew",
        "Customer"
    ]
    self.var.set(OPTIONS[0])
    return OptionMenu(parent, self.var, *OPTIONS)
```

I have removed the execution of `.pack()` so that you can use whatever layout manager you want later.

Then modify `widgets()` as below:

```
def widgets(self):
    self.head = Label(self.master, text='LOGIN', font=('', 35), pady=10)
    self.head.pack()
    self.logf = Frame(self.master, padx=10, pady=10)
    self.dropbox(self.logf).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
    Label(self.logf, text='Username: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(row=2, column=0)
    Entry(self.logf, textvariable=self.username, bd=5, font=('', 15)).grid(row=2, column=1)
    Label(self.logf, text='Password: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
    Entry(self.logf, textvariable=self.password, bd=5, font=('', 15), show='*').grid(row=3, column=1)
    Button(self.logf, text='Login', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.login).grid()
    Button(self.logf, text='Create Account', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.cr).grid(row=4, column=1)
    self.logf.pack()

    self.crf = Frame(self.master, padx=10, pady=10)
    Label(self.crf, text='Select:', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(row=1, column=0)
    self.dropbox(self.crf).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    Label(self.crf, text='Username: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
    Entry(self.crf, textvariable=self.n_username, bd=5, font=('', 15)).grid(row=2, column=1)
    Label(self.crf, text='Password: ', font=('', 20), pady=5, padx=5).grid(sticky=W)
    Entry(self.crf, textvariable=self.n_password, bd=5, font=('', 15), show='*').grid(row=3, column=1)
    Button(self.crf, text='Create Account', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.new_user).grid()
    Button(self.crf, text='Go to Login', bd=3, font=('', 15), padx=5, pady=5, command=self.log).grid(row=4, column=1)
```

Also I think the indentation of the below block in your code is wrong:

```
with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
    c = db.cursor()
# wrong indentation?
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (var TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL ,password TEXT NOT NULL);')
db.commit()
db.close()
```

It should be:

```
with sqlite3.connect('quit.db') as db:
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (var TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL ,password TEXT NOT NULL);')
    db.commit()
    # no need to call db.close() as the db will be closed when exiting the with block
```

Similar issue applies to other `with sqlite3.connect(...) as db` statement later in your code.

Comment: thanks so much, it all seems to be working smoothly now amazing